# Peculiar working of '*' in regex expression

Tags: regex, python-3.6

While writing a regex pattern for substituting all the continuos '1's and single '1's  as 's'. I found this quite confusing ,usage of '+' (used for matching 1 or more ) gave expected result, but '*' gave strange result

```
>>> l='100'
>>> import re
>>> j=re.compile(r'(1)*')    
>>> m=j.sub('*',l)
>>> m
'*0*0*'
```

While usage of '+' gave expected result.

```
>>> l='100'
>>> j=re.compile(r'1+')
>>> m=j.sub('*',l)
>>> m
'*00'
```

how does '*' in regex gives this, while its behaviour is to match 0 or more.

Comment: Perl, PHP, Java will output `**0*0*` for `/1*/` as regex

Comment: Very interesting question. If someone has the hands dirty in the python regex engine code, feel free to provide an explanation.

Comment: A little care while differing the roles of re.search() and re.sub() is very beneficial for (1)* useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(1)*` means "match 0 or more 1's". So for `100` it matches the 1, the empty string between 0 and 0, and the empty string after the last 0. You then replace the empty strings with '*'. 1+ requires at least one 1 in the match, so it won't match the boundary between characters.

For those readers curious, yes the python output is `*0*0*` and not `**0*0*`. Here is a test python [script](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22//repl.it/embed/I2Jz/0.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E) to play with. (Regex101 has the wrong output for this, because it does not use an actual python regex engine. Online Regex testers will usually use PCRE (which is provided in PHP and Apache HTTP Server), and fake the target regex engine. Always test your regex in live code!)

Here you can see in JavaScript the output will be `**0*0*` (it will match the empty string between 1 and 0 as a new match) This is a prime example of why 'regex flavor' is important. Different engines use slightly different rules. (in this case, if the new match starts at 0 or the character boundary)

```js
console.log("100".replace(/(1)*/g, '*'))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145819/discussion-on-answer-by-tezra-peculiar-working-of-in-regex-expression).

Answer (score 2):

Beware of patterns that can match nothing. This isn't well-defined, so the behaviour varies by engine. For example, you get a different result in Perl.

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say "100" =~ s/1*/\*/rg'
**0*0*
```

1. At position 0, it matches 1 character.
2. At position 1, it matches 0 characters.
3. [Forced to advance to avoid infinite loop]
4. At position 2, it matches 0 characters.
5. [Forced to advance to avoid infinite loop]
6. At position 3, it matches 0 characters.
7. [Forced to advance to avoid infinite loop]
8. [Fail to match: Beyond end of string]

Answer (score 2):

```
regex = r"1*"
p = re.compile(regex)
test_str = "100"
for m in p.finditer(test_str):
    print(m.start(), m.group())
```

Outputs 4 matches (that's why regex101 shows 4 matches):

```
0 1
1 
2 
3
```

While `re.sub()` replaces 3 positions which is a cause of `re.sub()` advancing after a zero-length match ([Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)):

> #### sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost **non-overlapping** occurrences of
>   *pattern* in string by the replacement *repl*.
>
> ...
>
> Empty matches for the pattern are replaced only when not adjacent to a
>   previous match, so `sub('x*', '-', 'abc')` returns `'-a-b-c-'`.

What does a non-overlapping occurrence mean? [It means when](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html):

> the first match ended at the start of the string, where the first
>   match attempt began. The regex engine needs a way to avoid getting
>   stuck in an infinite loop that forever finds the same zero-length
>   match at the start of the string.
>
> The simplest solution, which is used by most regex engines, is to
>   start the next match attempt one character after the end of the
>   previous match, if the previous match was zero-length.

In this case, the second match attempt begins at the position between the 1 and the 0 in the string, hence the difference.